# I am new to firebase. When I try to Upload data to firebase, I'm getting an error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

pc_0 - Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Firebase error. Please ensure that you have the URL of your Firebase Realtime Database instance configured correctly.

I created the database after connecting the app to firebase from the firebase assistant of android studio.

I tried to change the URL, but I searched everywhere and I couldn't find the URL to change it.

Comment: Most likely you need to redownload the google-service.json file and add the updated version to your app. If you tried doing that, edit your question to show the steps you took for it.